# Add a new client field to admin panel and manage it

Tags: craftcms

I'm new to Craft CMS and yii.  I just want to add a new (clients) field to craft 2 admin panel. This field must have the option to add edit delete a client, form fields are (name, account_id etc.). Currently, I'm following the tutorial https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/#who-it%E2%80%99s-for. How to build this, anyone knows please help me to solve this. If the custom plugins are the only way please give me some step by step procedure to solve this, thank you

Now I'm trying to create a new custom plugin, but I don't know is that a right way to solve this issue

Expecting some step by step procedure to solve this

Comment: Please help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own plugins. Refer this URL's
https://pluginfactory.io/ and https://github.com/nystudio107/generator-craftplugin. 
If you are not following these tutorials, then you can create your own plugins but that will be more time-consuming.